# Why $q$ in LWE must be polynomial in $n$

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe

I am wondering why the modulus $q$ in the LWE problem has to be polynomial in $n$.

Another question is whether one can take it to be an arbitrary integer instead of a prime number.

Comment: Are you asking why $q\in O(poly(n))$, or why $q\in \Omega(poly(n))$?

Comment: @Ievgeni It is $O(\text{poly}(n)$

Comment: Could you precise where did you see q should be in $O(poly(n))$?

Comment: @Ievgeni it is here
https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/lwesurvey.pdf
The section "Parameters" at the end of page 2. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is in the document you've found the recommendation : "Choosing an exponential modulus $q$ has the disadvantage
of significantly increasing the size of the input."

Comment: Yes but what is the input here? Input of what?

Comment: $(\vec a, 〈\vec a, s〉+ e)$